# php doesn't get the json values i send from curl

Tags: php, json, curl, urldecode

curl -i -X POST -d 'json={"Amount":1000,"idPlayers":1}' http://www.myurl.com/updateamount.php

My php code:

```
<?php

    $json = urldecode($_GET['jsonSendData']);
    $json = str_replace("\\", "", $json);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

// if i hard code it here it works fine, but need from a post from curl
//$json = '{"Amount":1000,"idPlayers":1}';

    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    echo "json = ", $json;

    $amount = mysql_real_escape_string($data['Amount']);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($data['idPlayers']);

    echo "Amount = ",$amount;
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to read post data and using the correct name:

```
$json = urldecode($_POST['json']);
```

Comment: My Xcode guy thinks i can do it like below so we don't have to send a 'json' value.  but it doesn't work either any ideas?
        $json = urldecode($_POST['json']);
 $json = str_replace("\\", "", $json);
 $data = json_decode($json, true);

// $amount = json_decode($_POST['Amount']);
// $player_id = json_decode($_POST['idPlayers']);